# No such module "FirebaseAnalytics"

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

I have a very annoying problem which I can't solve for two days now.
The problem is with FirebaseAnalytics pod. 
I have tried:
- "cleaning & building"
- adding path to framework search path
- adding the framework to the library in build phase section
BUT NO LUCK at all!!!

In addition, I have tried reinstalling pods over again - the issue still persisted.

Is there anything particular with FirebaseAnalytics framework? This was a dependency file that was created from 'Firebase/Core'. 
If it helps, I should say that the issue happened after updating 'Firebase/Messaging' pod to 'FirebaseMessaging' and discarding changes.

Comment: What is the error log stack? 
Current behavior and expected behavior?

Comment: Did you find a fix? Experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @AnthonySaltarelli oh I completely forgot to update this. Yeah, I actually did find a solution. First, what I did was to delete derived data folder in xCode for the project and then clean & building it again. If you have problems, just let me know, I'll come up with more details.

Comment: @MeiirbekAshirgaziyev is there any steps you haven't mentioned? I'm experiencing the same. But I already deleted derived data, cleaned the project and restarted xcode. Still having the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. First, what I did was to delete derived data folder in xCode for the project and then clean & building it again.

Answer (score -2):

I had no such module for Firebase in a view controller. Turned out I had capitalized the 'B' as in FireBase. Fixed the typo and issue was resolved.

I had an issue in appDelegate where FirebaseMessaging reported no such module, even though it appeared in pods.

I had tried the following from another Stack Overflow solution - it may also work for you

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods-deintegrate cocoapods-clean

$ pod deintegrate

$ pod clean

$ rm Podfile
```

Then remove the Xcode workspace, and proceed with a new fresh Pod install.

Some of these took a long time to complete. Be patient. It worked for me.

Comment: removing Podfile? Bad idea